# Can I use ilike to check the contents of a table in jsonb

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

```
SELECT 
    id,
    some_jsonb_table
FROM
    public.example
where some_jsonb_table::text ilike '%example_report%'
```

I tried to switch `some_jsonb_table` on `TEXT` but still `ILIKE` doesn't work.
How to check if the content of the table contains the text fragment I am searching for ?

Comment: why doesn't it work?  Are you getting an error, or is expected result not occuring?  can you share some sample data and sample output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jsonb_data::text ilike '%my_search_string%` should work perfectly

Take this sample table and query, it works even on nested jsonb objects

```
with a as (
select cast('{"brand": "Toyota", "color": ["red", "black"], "price": 285000}' as jsonb) jsonb_data
union  
select cast('{"brand": "Honda", "color": ["blue", "pink"], "price": 25000}' as jsonb)
)
select * from a 
where jsonb_data::text ilike '%blue%';
```

Result is as expected

```
jsonb_data
{"brand": "Honda", "color": ["blue", "pink"], "price": 25000}
```

You can also use alternative operators

```
with a as (
select cast('{"brand": "Toyota", "color": ["red", "black"], "price": 285000, "sold": true}' as jsonb) jsonb_data
union  
select cast('{"brand": "Honda", "color": {"good":[["blue"], "pink"]}, "price": 25000, "sold": false}' as jsonb)
)
select * from a 
where jsonb_data ->> 'color' ~* 'blue';
```

[Good resource on jsonb in PostreSQL](https://haselt.com/blog/working-with-postgresql-jsonb)